# OpenLayers draw shortest path between two points near [-180] [180] longitude

Tags: openlayers

I have two points I would like to connect via line string:

```js
 var a = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-159.6597257, 21.995953]);
 var b = ol.proj.fromLonLat([166.644261, 19.279499]);
```

Is there a way to draw this line in a way it would not cross the globe.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82dgrwny/

[image: around the world]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenLayers understands "wrapped" coorrdinates. Use either

```
 var a = ol.proj.fromLonLat([360 - 159.6597257, 21.995953]);
```

or

```
var b = ol.proj.fromLonLat([166.644261 - 360, 19.279499]);
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hg5vm4dn/)

[image: screenshot of map with update]